# What doesn't get inherited in .Net?

Tags: .net, inheritance

I guess I was surprised to learn that `Implements` or `<Serializable()>`  do not get inherited from class to class which means that it must be redefined each I want to recreated those behaviors. I was wondering what else isn't inhertible in .Net?  Thanks

Comment: Mhh, are you sure of this?I didn't notice this strange behaviour

Comment: No, interface implementations definitely get inherited.  Attributes can be, either automatically with AttributeUsage or manually by just searching the base classes for the attribute.  Maybe Private members are a better example.  They get inherited, you can however not use them.  Might as well call it 'not inherited'.

Comment: Ok, so I have a base class A that implements interface IA, which IA has declared method Do as defined method.  If B class inherits A, and B class tries to Implement IA.Do, the complier complains that "Interface 'IA' is not implemented by this class".  Does this mean that class B implements IA too befoe it can tie the method IA.Do to B?  This is where I got the basis of the original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are 2 different items: interface and attribute inheritance.

The `Inherits` portion refers to how interfaces behave across class hierarchies.  Interfaces are indeed inherited.  If a given base class implements `IFactory` then all of it's derived types will.  There are certain language oddities on how a derived class can re-implement the interface or specific methods.  However at a .Net level once a base class implements an interface all derived classes will as well.

Whether or not an attribute is inherited depends on the value of `AttributeUsage.Inherited` on the `AttributeUsage` for the given attribute.  In the case of `Serializable` it's marked as `Inherits=false` and won't be inherited.  Every attribute must pick their own behavior here.

Answer (score 1):

The long answer would take too long, but the short answer is any class using the `sealed` (c#) or `NotInheritable` (VB.NET) modifier.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: My appologies.  The accept button doesn't always work for me and actually submitted a bug to meta.serverfault.com.  Trying to recreate the problem as its hit and miss.  Ive refreshed the page 50 times and only a third of the time I can toggle between answers.  Sometimes it wont accept at all and sometimes it accepts once but doesnt toggle anymore.

http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2135/accept-button-does-not-work-all-the-time